# Decryption Memory Issue

Tags: c++, crypto++

I've recently been making a server which uses AES256 to encrypt/decrypt data, it took awhile to get it to send correctly. However now I'm having an issue I believe is down to memory, if I send the word "hello" it'll decrypt fine, if I then send "helloo", it'll also decrypt fine, but if I send anything shorter than "helloo" after, it'll error during decryption and if you print the encrypted string it received it's got what it should have plus the additional length of the old string.

e.g

```
hello:  ####################
helloo: ##############################
hi:     #####(#########################) //has the additional length made up from the encrypted string of "helloo" minus the first however many characters "hi" is
```

The code:

```
std::string decryptString(std::string ciphertext, byte *key, byte *iv)
{
    std::string decodedtext;
    CryptoPP::StringSource(ciphertext, true, 
                           new CryptoPP::HexDecoder(new CryptoPP::StringSink(decodedtext)));

    std::string plaintext;

    CryptoPP::GCM<CryptoPP::AES>::Decryption dec;
    dec.SetKeyWithIV((const byte *)key, CryptoPP::AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH, 
                     (const byte *)iv, CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE);

    CryptoPP::AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter adf(dec, new CryptoPP::StringSink(plaintext));

    adf.Put((const byte *)decodedtext.data(), decodedtext.size());
    adf.MessageEnd();

    return plaintext;
}
```

Comment: i'd guess you don't reinitialize your buffer for the encrypted output, but without the code ... hard to tell

Comment: Now post the code that does the **encryption**.

Comment: can you show us the code that calls decryptString(...) ? i think `cyphertext` still contains the old string when you put the new one in ... try writing a \0 after the chars of the new string

Comment: BTW, when a function takes `const byte *` as an argument and you have a `byte *`, you don't need to cast it to `const byte *`.  (That has nothing to do with your problem, mind you.)

Comment: What is the size of your key and iv? And how do you initialize them? What is the tag size? And what does the encryption routine look like? The Crypto++ wiki has an example at [GCM Mode](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Gcm).

Answer (score 1):

Try using valgrind to find memory errors in your code.

Oh, and a tip: post the code itself, it might lead to more interesting answers.

Comment: I will try using what you've mentioned, I've also added the code to the post.

Answer (score 0):

If you always pass the same initialization vector to this method, may be the reason is in it. Try

```
dec.Resynchronize(iv);
```